# what is the use case for start(),awaitTermination() and stop() with regard to spark-streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

New to spark-streaming,
I am developing an application that fetches data from terminal and loads into HDFS.
I searched over the internet but could not understand how to stop a spark streaming application, once it is triggered.

Also, would appreciate if you could explain me use case for `sc. awaitTermination()` and `sc.stop()`.

Comment: It's explained here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#initializing-streamingcontext

Answer (score 12):

`streamingContext.awaitTermination()` --> *it just waits for the termination signal from user*. When it receives signal from user (i.e CTRL+C or SIGTERM) then it streaming context will be stopped. It is kind of shutdownhook in java.

`streamingContext.stop` will stop the streaming context immediately. You can even tell the streaming context about spark context. If you want to stop only streaming context and not spark context then you can call `streamingContext.stop(false)`

Comment: Thanks Raju, streamingContext.awaitTermination() --> does it terminates program gracefully?

Comment: Yes, it terminates gracefully. User will get exceptions in case of errors while stopping.  You can even use streamingContext.stop(stopSparkContext: Boolean, stopGracefully: Boolean) api for graceful shutdown. You can use this method in shutdown hook in your application (i.e. driver code).

Comment: sys.ShutdownHookThread {
  logger.info("Gracefully stopping Application...")
  ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)
  logger.info("Application stopped gracefully")
}

Comment: yes. Something similar like this   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {         
   ssc.stop(true, true) }
});

Answer (score 5):

**start** - Till this point the actual execution of the code does not start. After start() the JobScheduler starts, this in turn starts JobGenerator which creates the jobs.

**awaitTermination** - It internally uses some condition variable which keeps a check on whether stop() was invoked explicitly in code or the application terminated (Ctrl+C).

Answer (score 3):

Stream queries are expected to run for a long time. Once a query is started(**start**), the executors will keep running, while the driver will be idle. To prevent the driver process from exiting, call **awaitTermination**; then when it is really time to stop the query, call **stop**.